# How can we write the Navier-Stokes equations on rotating sphere intrinsically?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, fluid-dynamics

The Navier-Stokes equations in $\mathbb{R}^n$ read $$u_t+u\cdot \nabla u -\mu \Delta u +\nabla p =f$$
$$\nabla \cdot u =0.$$
I had a look at a paper by Maryam Samavaki and Jukka Tuomela titled "Navier-Stokes equations on Riemannian manifolds" and they propose that on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ the Navier-Stokes equations become $$u_t+\nabla_u u-\mu Lu +\operatorname{grad}(p)=0$$
$$\operatorname{div} (u)=0$$ where $Lu=\Delta_B u+\operatorname{grad}(\operatorname{div}(u)) +\operatorname{Ric}(u)$ and $\Delta_B u=\operatorname{div}(g^{ij} u^k_{;i}).$

But I was wondering how can we write the above equations on a rotating sphere, I know that in theoretical meteorology they use the Navier-Stokes equations on rotating sphere extrinsically but I would like to know what the intrinsic approach would be.

So how can we do this?

Comment: What would it mean for a sphere (as a manifold) to be intrinsically rotating?

Comment: Maybe the coordinate system depends on time, so given a chart $(U,\phi (t))$ , the projections $x_1(t),...,x_n(t)$ depend on $t$, I don't know if this makes any sense, though and if it does I definitely don't know how to formalize it.

Comment: This does not really make sense to me, but this could be because I never encountered such a thing (although I am a differential geometer). The sphere is a manifold, it has a maximal atlas that is attached to it, which is independent of any time parameter.